# Foreach loop go to next iteration without waitng for current iteration

Tags: java, asynchronous, methods, foreach

Inside a foreach loop I invoke a method:

```
for (Iterable pl : ilist) {

myMethod();

}
```

myMethod() might take a long time for currennt (like minutes or days) p1 Object, but wile executingI want to proceed to th e next iteration.(This could be called an async call as far as I know)

Is that even possible with a foreach loop?

Comment: No it's not possible. You can use threads here IMO. Or wait for Java-8 which will allow parallel streaming of iterables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to spawn a new `Thread` for each iteration of your loop.  I might do it something like this.

```
for ( /* whatever */ ) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            myMethod();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Keep it simple approach.
I like that!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to schedule these tasks to complete asynchronously, you can create a new Runnable and hand it off to an ExecutorService to run the operation on another thread. Now you need to know what to do with the results from this task.

```
// ExecutorService Thread Pool with 10 threads
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

public void iterate(Collection<?> collection) {
    for (Object o : collection) {
        executor.execute(createTask(o));
    }

}

public Runnable createTask(final Object o) {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // do task.
        }
    };
}
```

You will want to look at Callable and Future to get more sophisticated.

Comment: Cool & sophisticated solution.
But why not implement  David Wallace's solution?
I want to keep it simple!

Comment: @SoulMagnet The use of an ExecutorService over just starting threads is manyfold. Firstly, using an ExecutorService enables you to manage the behavior of your threads. You can retain a thread pool with limits on size and execution behavior, and you can more easily control the thread lifecycle behavior. Without a threadpool to manage this behavior, you place a greater burden on the developer to manage each thread. The example I provided is not the *best* method for managing threads in your application from an architectural standpoint, but it does demonstrate how to use an ExecutorService.